# Can we add voting for tag synonyms in the abillities list for faq?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms, faq-update-request

For the ability list:

> 15     Vote up
>
> 15    Flag offensive
>
> 50    Leave comments†
>
> 100   Vote down (costs 1 rep)
>
> 100   Edit community wiki posts
>
> 200   Reduced advertising
>
> 250   Vote to close, reopen, or migrate
>   your questions
>
> 500   Retag questions
>
> 1000  Show total up and down vote
>   counts
>
> 1500  Create new tags
>
> 2000  Edit other people's posts
>
> 3000  Vote to close, reopen, or
>   migrate any questions
>
> 10000     Delete closed questions, access
>   to moderation tools

It says nothing about the fact that you can vote for tag synonyms at 2000. Can we add that?

Answer (score 1):

Yerp, this was done a while back, create and vote are the same privilege.